# В каком случае пишется «тоже», а в каком - «то же»?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

Нужно разъяснение с примерами на «тоже» и «то же».

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Выполните домашнюю работу сами или начните выполнять, и здесь её проверят.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не учащийся, поэтому домашней работы у меня никак не может быть. Мне просто нужно пояснение данного вопроса, который я задал выше :)

Comment: Гугл в помощь: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/slitno-ili-razdelno-pishetsya-slovo-tozhe.html